# Two neighbourhoods $V_\delta(a)$ and $V_\epsilon(b)$ are disjoint iff $\epsilon+\delta\le|b-a|$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm beginning studying real analysis, and this came up in the book, without proof:

($V_\epsilon(a)$ denotes the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$)

> For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$; $\delta,\epsilon >0$ : 
>   $\epsilon+\delta \le \lvert b-a \rvert \iff V_\delta(a) \cap V_\epsilon(b) = \emptyset$

I easily proved that the left side implies the right, by contradiction, but I can't find how to prove the rest. I tried to show that there's an $x$ for which $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|x-b|<\epsilon$ when the left side is false, thinking that $x=(a+\delta+b-\epsilon)/2$ works (when $a\le b$), but it is either wrong, or I can't get to the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What book is that?  What is $V$?  Please include more context to the question.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Vε(a) denotes the ε-neighbourhood of a

Comment: $x=\frac{a+\delta \;+\;b-\varepsilon}2$ should indeed work. Which trouble do you run into when trying to prove it is in both of the balls?

Comment: Note that you can also assume that $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are both $\le|b-a|$, because if not then either $a$ or $b$ will be in the intersection and you're done. That just leaves a case where $a \le b-\varepsilon < a+\delta \le b$, where it should be easy to prove that your $x$ works.

Comment: I try to prove that that x belongs to Vδ(a) first. so I substitute it in |x-a|, getting |(-a+δ+b-ε)/2|. I try to prove that that is less than δ, but no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, lets assume that $a<b.$ Let $V_\delta(a) \cap V_\epsilon(b) = \emptyset,$ so there is an $x\in(a,b)$ s.t. $|x-a|\geq \delta$ and $|x-b|\geq \epsilon.$ Since $x\in (a,b),$ we have $x-a>0$ and $b-x>0.$ Then: $$\delta +\epsilon \leq |x-a|+|x-b|= x-a-(x-b)=b-a=|b-a|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality assume that $a<b$

There are four numbers to look at:

$$a-\delta, a+\delta, b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon$$

The intersection of $$ ( 
a-\delta, a+\delta)$$ and $$(b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$$ is empty if and only if  $$
a+\delta \le b-\epsilon$$
Which is equivalent to $$ \delta +\epsilon \le b-a$$

Thus the intersection is not empty if and only if  $$ \delta +\epsilon >b-a$$